# Scalaxb ignore unknown fields

Tags: scala, scalaxb, sbt-scalaxb

When your server have added new fields for response your client will fail if we don't let scalaxb know to ignore unknown fields its like @JsonIgnore in jackson.

Answer (score 0):

For this it has a very solution. Just add scalaxbIgnoreUnknown in (Compile, scalaxb) := true in your build tool sample code for build.sbt

````
```lazy val helloModule = (project in file(".")).settings(
commonSettings,
publishSetting,
scalaxbIgnoreUnknown in (Compile, scalaxb) := true,
scalaxbDispatchVersion in (Compile, scalaxb) := vDispatch,
scalaxbPackageName in (Compile, scalaxb)     := "com.hello.helloModule.client",
libraryDependencies := Seq(
      "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4",
      "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "2.0.0-M2",


      "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % vDispatch,
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.1.0"
    ),
name := "com.hello.helloModule.client").enablePlugins(ScalaxbPlugin)```
````

Comment: P.S you need to have scalaxb version greater than 1.4.0

Commit in scalaxb repo for support
https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/pull/310